# .NET Entity Framework Core one-many relationship

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

When I tried to create tables using EF, I saw that the name of FK in the User table is different from my expectation, and also 'allow null'. I intended to create the FK 'orgId' under the 'User' table. I referred to the [website](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx) this. In the case of the sample, it created a Foreign Key for 'Grade' below the 'Student' table. Could you tell me what I missed here? (*I used EntityFrameworkCore@3.1.0)
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int userId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string userEmail { get; set; }
        public string previousPW { get; set; }
        public string userHashedPassword { get; set; }
        public DateTime userResetPWDate { get; set; }
        public string userResetCode { get; set; }
        public string userFullName { get; set; }
        public string userOrgName { get; set; }
        public string userJobTitle { get; set; }
        public string userFName { get; set; }
        public string userLName { get; set; }
        public string userPhone { get; set; }
        public string userFax { get; set; }
        public string userLevel { get; set; }
        public DateTime userCreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime userAccessedDate { get; set; }
        public string userComment { get; set; }

        public int orgId { get; set; }
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PermissionPkgView> PermissionPkgView { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Domain
{
    public class Organization
    {
        [Key]
        public int orgId { get; set; }
        public string orgName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As some of the comments, I tried to follow the way, the same as the reference.

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Grade Grade { get; set; }
    }
}
----
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Domain
{
    public class Grade
    {
        public int GradeID { get; set; }
        public string GradeName { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, the result is different from the sample. It created 'FK_Student_Grade_GradeID' with allowing null.

[image]

Comment: clarify "User table is different from my expectation".  what is your expectation, and what qualifies that expectation regarding the name?  Also, please provide the properties of that FK, the name certainly gives an indication, but it isn't definition of it.  Also, your link references to Code First EF6 (may be worth attribute\tagging).  this also means that in some regards you're asking for insight to explain tutorial code (other people's code).  This can be problematic, since there could be an out of context reason\lesson.

Comment: "it created a Foreign Key for 'Grade' below the 'Student' table", your provide code doesn't represent anything about Grades or a relationship in that respect, is it relevant to your inquiry?

Comment: after looking at your linked tutorial sample code, (which is using `Grade` as opposed to `Organization`) it's clearer to me that your question is a comparison of your implement to that of the sample code.  please include that sample code in your question, and\or describe the differences between them.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank you for your comment. My expectation is that FK is created named 'orgId' under the 'User' table. However, the current FK is created named 'FK_User_Organization_OrganizationorgId' with allowing Null.

Comment: well.. it's already bad sample code and comparison. `Student` and `Grade` are not even one to many relationship in the sample (which is supposed to be in regards to conventions around one-to-many, but isn't). So, you're comparing apple and oranges here..  Apart from that, I don't think the FK generated it's name without 'FK' in the name to begin with. Author probably changed the name of the constraint.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Really? Is it a normal way to make a one-to-many relationship in EF Core?

Comment: ah..nevermind, I'm wrong.. I confused myself there (my initial intent here was just to curate the question).. why are you adding `ICollection` types and why are you doing `virtual` to `Organization` on `User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just use 'Fluent API', then it shows FK normally.
[image]

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Domain;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<tbl_PW> tbl_PW { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Organization> Organization { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<Organization>(u => u.Organization)
            .WithMany(o => o.User)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.orgId);
        }
    }
}
```